Gaps-and-islands: get time spent in state
I have a table recording states and timestamps, like this one:



id
serialno
state
timestamp




1
100100100
True
01:02:02


2
100100100
True
01:02:14


3
100100100
False
01:02:15


4
100100100
True
01:02:26


5
100100100
True
01:02:46



And I would need to get the time spent within each state, whereas the end time for each state is the timestamp value of the next record; like this:



id
serialno
state
timestamp
duration




1
100100100
True
01:02:02
12


2
100100100
True
01:02:14
1


3
100100100
False
01:02:15
11


4
100100100
True
01:02:26
20


5
100100100
True
01:02:46
(ongoing)



And the expected result would be:



serialno
state
duration




100100100
True
12 + 1 + 20 = 42


100100100
False
11



I tried using the LAG() and LEAD() window-functions, but could not get the expected result.
Could you please help me?
Thanks a lot in advance!

based on your desired output doesn't look like a gap & island problem.see my answer but if this really an gap and island problem give us a better example

you can use window function lead() like so:
with cte as (
  select serialno
  , state 
  , lead(timestamp) over (partition by serialno order by timestamp) - timestamp as duration
  from DeviceState
)
  
select serialno, state, sum(duration) as duration
from cte 
group by serialno, state

output:



serialno
state
duration




100100100
t
00:00:33


100100100
f
00:00:11



fiddle

Thanks a lot! I was too focussed on getting the intermediate result first. Simple and efficient. Really, thanks a lot!
